Angular AG Grid - Content Security Policy (CSP) Nonce
While applying CSP nonce for scripts and styles, I ran into a problem for ag-grid (https://www.ag-grid.com/).
I followed approach mentioned in angular csp documentation (https://angular.dev/best-practices/security#content-security-policy). I've set the ngCspNonce attribute on the root application element. I see console errors as shown below. Nonce was working for all controls except ag-grid.

Clicking on dom.mjs showing below script is blocked.

Please advise how to make Content Security Policy Nonce to work for ag-grid.

It's not possible to use the CSP style-src nonce policy with AG Grid. To cite the docs:

The style-src policy requires the unsafe-inline due to the DOM Row and Column Virtualisation.
The technique the grid uses to display position rows requires explicit positioning of the rows and columns.
This positioning is only possible using CSS style attributes to set explicit X and Y positions.
This is a feature that all data grids have.
Without it, the data grid would have a very low limit on the amount of data that could be displayed

